# Merging dataframes and ignoring duplicates indices (selectively) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'd like to concatenate two dataframes df1, df2 to a new one where values in duplicate indices/columns are assigned as `NA` if they exist in both df1 and df2, but real values considered should they exist in only one:

df1:

```
    A    B    C
X   NA   1    2    #Note: (X,B) also in df2
Y   3    2    NA   #Note: (Y,B) also in df2
Z   NA   NA   4
```

df2:

```
    A    B    F
X   -1   -1   NA    #Note: (X,A) not in df1
Y   NA   -3   -4    #Note: (Y,A) not in df1
W   NA   -3   -4
```

Output:

```
    A    B    C    F
X   -1   NA   2    NA
Y   3    NA   NA   -4
Z   NA   NA   4    NA
W   NA   -3   NA   -4
```

I think that something like `pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)` should work, but I dont know how to make the special condition for the indices/columns that have values.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and then replace `NaN` by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) - `mask` is created by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) and `&`, `NaN` are replaced to `False` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
mask = (df1.notnull() & df2.notnull()).fillna(False)
print (mask)
       A      B      C      F
W  False  False  False  False
X  False   True  False  False
Y  False   True  False  False
Z  False  False  False  False

#if necessary change order of index values add reindex
df = df1.combine_first(df2).reindex(['X','Y','Z', 'W'])
print (df)
     A    B    C    F
X -1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
Y  3.0  2.0  NaN -4.0
Z  NaN  NaN  4.0  NaN
W  NaN -3.0  NaN -4.0

print (df.mask(mask))
     A    B    C    F
X -1.0  NaN  2.0  NaN
Y  3.0  NaN  NaN -4.0
Z  NaN  NaN  4.0  NaN
W  NaN -3.0  NaN -4.0
```

Comment: I was trying to ping you in chat to tell you this, but couldn't. I really appreciate all your effort in helping me! You have already taught me so much in my last few questions, thanks so much!

Comment: I have email in my profile ;) And thank you for all yesterday acceptings ;) Nice day.